# How to make update table if exists otherwise create

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have dynamodb table: `tablename: mytable`

- schema: {'primary_key': 'name'}

Case 1

- Insert document {'name':'john', 'age': 24} if not exists in the table otherwise update the item

Do i need to get the item from dynamo and check whether 'name exists' in the beginning to do the operation?

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = client.Table("mytable")
    try:
        table.put_item(Item= {'name':'john', 'age': 24})
    except:
        table.update_item(Item= {'name':'john', 'age': 24})
```

Case 2

- update the document {'name':'john', 'age': 24} exists in the table otherwise `don't create` new item

Do I need to get the item from dynamo and check whether 'name exists' in the beginning to do the operation?

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = client.Table("mytable")
    try:
        table.update_item(Item= {'name':'john', 'age': 24})
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understanding the nature of [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) will help you here:

*Edits an existing item's attributes, or adds a new item to the table if it does not already exist.*

Case 1, is handled by default when using UpdateItem, as it will update if item exists and if it does not it will create a new one.

Case 2, you will need to use a [ConditionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-ConditionExpression) where you state `attribute_exists` meaning if it exists the item will be updated, if it does not exist the update will fail with `ConditionCheckFailedException`.

Comment: can you update the python code also>

Comment: Sample code can be found here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/tree/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/python

Comment: saw the examples, can you ping the ConditionExpression git url

Comment: Stackoverflow is not rent a developer. What have you tried, where is it failing?